# Dismissing a dialog fragment which is launched from another dialog fragment results in illegal state exception

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

```
DialogFragment customCurrentDialogFragment; -> custom dialog
```

Launching the dialog from another dialog fragment(fragment A) :

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();  
customCurrentDialogFragment = new CustomLoader();  
customCurrentDialogFragment.setCancelable(false);  
customCurrentDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, "dialog");
```

Dismissing in fragment A :

```
customCurrentDialogFragment.dismiss();
```

Comment: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState - this is the error message which we are getting, can any one suggest a work around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `dismissAllowingStateLoss()` method of DialogFragment.

Since you are calling show() method using fragment manager, you could use dismissAllowingStateLoss() method to dismiss the dialog fragment. Meanwhile this doesn't work if you use show() method using fragment transaction because popBackStack calls enqueueAction() with `allowStateLoss = false`

Comment: using dismissAllowStateLoss helped the issue.